# Удалить сайт из Chrome встроенного hsts списка

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

Всем привет!

В процессе разработки приходится использовать тестовый сайт google-analyics.com который ссылается на отличающийся от оригинального ip.

Но google-analyics.com есть в списке встроенных HSTS сайтов и удалить его оттуда используя chrome://net-internals/#hsts нельзя.

Вариант с использованием Firefox, где можно "Забыть сайт" в "about:permissions" так же не работает, так как эту функцию убрали из него уже.

Есть ли какой-то способ все-таки удалить из Google Chrome из предзагруженного списка сайт, сказав ему таки что я понимаю что я делаю) ?

Comment: Ответа на вопрос не знаю, но могу предложить как-нибудь подделать ssl-сертификат для сайта и скормить браузерам поддельный корневой сертификат (тот, которым подписывается сертификат сайта) как доверенный, может прокатит и не надо будет из hsts убирать